# Initializing multidimensional arrays in C with dynamic alocation

Tags: c

I found on google that If you want to dynamic alocate a 2d array in C you need to use this piece of code

```
    int **arr = (int **)malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
```

I want to ask if and why is really necessary to cast the malloc to (int **). I tested without the (int **) cast and it worked just fine for me, but everywhere on the internet I found that you should use the cast and I don't understand why. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't cast it. Perhaps the confusion stems from the fact that the code is also valid in C++, a different language in which this line of code only works with the cast.

Comment: @Blaze Ok, thanks. I found on google code that on 1d array didn't use the cast and on 2d array used the cast. I think that the code for 2d array was in C++ not C